# Extract String/Value of XML Key Without Etree

Tags: python, xml, plist

I need to extract a string from an xml file, but without the use of etree.

Small part of the XML:

```
<key>FDisplayName</key>
<string>Dripo</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.getdripo.dripo</string>
<key>DTXcode</key>
```

Say I wanted to extract `com.getdripo.dripo`, how could I do this, but without the use of etree?

I only know how to do it with etree, but in this case I cannot use it.

Couldn't find anything online, any ideas?

Comment: ... By writing a full XML parser yourself? Or using regular string functions? What is ever so wrong with `etree`, by the way?

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm having troubles installing the module (on iOS)

Comment: @mhawke Oh, yes. Python 2.7.8

Comment: What Python are you using for iOS, [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/)? It should have `etree` in the standard library. There are other parsers such as [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom).

Answer (score 1):

Using regex.

```
import re
s = """<key>FDisplayName</key>
<string>Dripo</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.getdripo.dripo</string>
<key>DTXcode</key>"""

print re.findall("<string>(.*?)</string>", s)      #finds all content between '<string>' tag
print re.findall("<string>(com.*?)</string>", s)
```

**Output:**

```
['Dripo', 'com.getdripo.dripo']
['com.getdripo.dripo']
```

**Note:** Highly suggest to use an XML parser.